# external svg plugged in by <object> has no reaction on change height in svg

Tags: html, css, svg, size

I have external svg:

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css" ?>
<svg class="header__nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M30.75 14.75H1.25C0.559625 14.75 0 15.1082 0 15.55C0 15.9918 0.559625 16.35 1.25 16.35H30.75C31.4404 16.35 32 15.9918 32 15.55C32 15.1082 31.4404 14.75 30.75 14.75Z" fill="#444444"/>
<path d="M30.75 4.75H1.25C0.559625 4.75 0 5.10816 0 5.55C0 5.99184 0.559625 6.35 1.25 6.35H30.75C31.4404 6.35 32 5.99184 32 5.55C32 5.10816 31.4404 4.75 30.75 4.75Z" fill="#444444"/>
<path d="M30.75 24.75H1.25C0.559625 24.75 0 25.1082 0 25.55C0 25.9918 0.559625 26.35 1.25 26.35H30.75C31.4404 26.35 32 25.9918 32 25.55C32 25.1082 31.4404 24.75 30.75 24.75Z" fill="#444444"/>
</svg>
```

If I set default value of height `height="30px"` everything works perfectly, but in this case I can't set size properties in css anyway

I have next css but it doesn't work and svg stay 0x0 sized:

```css
.header__nav-icon {
  height: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .header__nav-icon {
    height: 24px;
  }
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem but rather a common misconception about the svg `<object>` 'embedding' method:

Granted your svg is on the same domain:

```
<object class="svgObject" id="svgObject" data="navicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

You could access the svg DOM by javaScript like this:

```
let svgObject = document.querySelector('object[type="image/svg+xml"]');
if(svgObject){
svgObject.addEventListener("load",function(){
    let svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;
    let objectSvg = svgDoc.querySelector('svg');
    objectSvg.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
    objectSvg.setAttribute('height', '32');
});
}
```

Most importantly, you need something like a load eventListener, since your **svg data isn't instantly available for DOM manipulations** or css styling.

If you're aiming at best css styling (or as well js processing) abilities – I'd rather recommend an 'inline svg' approach like this:

```css
.svgInline{
    display:inline-block;
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
    font-size:32px;
}

.green{
  color:green;
}

.baselineAdjust .svgInline{
    position:relative;
    bottom:-0.15em;
    height:1em;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

```html
<svg class="header__nav-icon" style="display:none" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="naviconInline" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 32 32" >
        <path id="hStroke" d="M30.75 4.75H1.25c-.69 0-1.25.36-1.25.8 0 .44.56.8 1.25.8h29.5c.69 0 1.25-.36 1.25-.8 0-.44-.56-.8-1.25-.8Z"/>
        <use href="#hStroke" />
        <use href="#hStroke" y="10" />
        <use href="#hStroke" y="20" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<h3>SVG inlined (reused)</h3>
<p class="green baselineAdjust">
    <svg class="svgInline" >
        <use href="#naviconInline" />
    </svg>
     Navigation
</p>
```

Worth reading: [csstricks.com: Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#using-svg-as-an-object)